# Adapting text size to image & screen size in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here is a the [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pr44bcu0/1/) to my SSCCE, but the gist of my code is below. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 4.0 to make a simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FooBar</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center mx-auto">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 well-lg">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/smeeb-public-images/foobar.png" class="img-fluid mx-auto img-rounded" alt="FooBar logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 well-lg">
        <h1 style="color: rgb(0, 170, 236); font-size: 40px;">FOOBAR</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 well-lg alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Oops!</strong> Something went wrong!
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 well-lg">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign In</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 well-lg">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the jsFiddle, there are several glaring issues:

1. The image is **way** too big; and
2. The `h1` title under the image is *way* too small; and
3. Both the image + title aren't horizontally centered on a large screen/viewport

I'm trying to tune either the bootstrap classes or the CSS stylings directly so that:

- The image and title are always perfectly centered
- On a larger screen (desktop/laptop browser), the image *only* takes up maybe 20% height + width of the screen
- On a smaller screen (mobile), the image takes up most of the width of the screen, maybe with a few % of padding on both sides
- In all cases, the `h1` title does its best to resize the text so that its width is more or less the same width of the image

**Can anyone see where I'm going awry?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you might do. Obviously the details of the styles are up to you to match your exact preference.

```css
.well-lg img{
  width:20%;
}

body{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}



@media screen and (max-width:468px){
  .well-lg img{
    width:80%;
  }
  .well-lg h1{
    font-size:4em !important;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FooBar</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center mx-auto">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 well-lg">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/smeeb-public-images/foobar.png" class="img-fluid mx-auto img-rounded" alt="FooBar logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 well-lg">
        <h1 style="color: rgb(0, 170, 236); font-size: 40px;">FOOBAR</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 well-lg alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Oops!</strong> Something went wrong!
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 well-lg">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign In</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 well-lg">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```